# Property 'original_title' does not exist on type 'string' > TypeScript

Tags: typescript, redux, react-typescript, react-tsx

So, I am creating a website with typescript and redux and I am pulling an API from TMDB (the movie database), I have setup my redux and i got the store, after using use selector and useDispatch I should be able to map through the array, but when I try to map through it I get this error message. This is my first time working with typescript and its confusing me.

App.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { loadMovies } from './redux/actions'
import { IMovieState } from './redux/reducer'
import './App.css'



function App() {
let dispatch = useDispatch()
const  moviesState = useSelector((state: IMovieState) => state.movie)
useEffect(() => {
dispatch(loadMovies())
}, [dispatch])
return <div className="App">
{moviesState && moviesState.map(mov => {
  return (
    <li>{mov.original_title}</li>
  )
})}
</div>
 }

export default App
```

Reducer.ts

```
import { Action } from './actions'

export interface IMovieState {
movie: string[]
}
const initalState = {
movie: [],
}

export const movieReducer = (
state: IMovieState = initalState,
action: Action,
) => {
switch (action.type) {
case 'GET_MOVIES': {
  return { ...state, movies: [...state.movie, action.payload] }
}
default:
  return state
 }
}
```

Actions.ts

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { Dispatch } from 'redux'

 export type Action = { type: 'GET_MOVIES'; payload: string }

 const getMovies = (movies: string): Action => ({
 type: 'GET_MOVIES',
 payload: movies,
 })

 export const loadMovies = () => {
 return function (dispatch: Dispatch) {
 axios
  .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
  .then((res) => {
    dispatch(getMovies(res.data))
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }
 }
```

Store.ts

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
import  rootReducer  from '../redux/rootReducer'

 const middlewares = [reduxThunk]

 export const store = createStore(rootReducer, 
 composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)))
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you expect a string to have an "original_title" property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `IMovieState` as this:

```
export interface IMovieState {
   movie: string[]
}
```

which has a `movie` property that is an array of `string` values, so you don't have any `original_title` in that type.

I guess what you need to do is to change your type like this:

```
interface IMovie {
   original_title: string; // or your prefered type
}
export interface IMovieState {
   movie: IMovie[]
}
```

Comment: Thank Taghi you this actually did the trick, this is like a puzzle to me im still getting to know typescript, big thanks!

Comment: @FarukSuljagic Glad I could help. have fun learning typescript ;)